# System of linear equation based on Sum of the Digits of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

My friend gave me this problem which I have not been able to solve:

> Let $S(k)$ denote the sum of the digits of $k$. Find all natural solutions $(x,y,z)$ to the equations:
>
> $S(x) + S(y) + S(z) = y-4$
>
> $S(x) + S(y) = x$
>
> $x + y + S(z) = z$

Any help in solving this(I would like to have some hints)?

Edit: Solutions are ok too please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x=S(x) \mod 9$ etc.

So $x$ and $y$ are multiples of 9, and $z = 5 \mod 9$.

If $y = 9$ then $y=S(y)$ and the first equation would give $S(x) + S(z) = -4$ which is impossible. So $y \ge 18$.

If $x = 9$ then $x=S(X)$ and the second equation would give $S(y)=0$ which is impossible. So $x \ge 18$.

And $z > x+y$. So $x \in \{18,27,36 \dots\}$, $y \in \{18, 27, 36 \dots \}$, $z \in \{41, 50, 59, \dots \}$.

I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: $S(a)$ is like a logarithm, for $a$ reasonably large $S(a) \ll a$ and we will not have a solution if any of $x,y,z$ are too large.

Comment: I'm trying but there seem to be no solutions, is that correct?

Comment: Hint: Try $S(x)=S(y)=9$.

Comment: There are at least two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

For each equation, pick some rather large value of your choice for the only variable that appears twice. What does the equation become?

Edit: Consider equation $1$. We are looking for solutions with, say, $y=1000$. 
Then we want to find $x,z$ such that $S(x)+S(z)=996-1=995$. 
So pick $z=1$, $x=1......1$ ($994$ ones) and we get a solution.

Edit 2: you can combine the equations to get a linear relation between $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Is it allowed to do that? Because it is said to find solutions.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, you just need to find one solution for each, not all solutions.

Comment: I don't think I get it. How does your method help us find solutions? Can you give an outline of your proof please?

Comment: Oh, did you mean a solution to all equations?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question if its not clear :p

Comment: Then my answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To get you started, take the second equation modulo 9 to get $S(y) \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$, so $y = 9k$ for some natural $k$.